# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchSessionException

Tags: ios, iphone, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

New to Appium/Java/Selenium and wondering if someone can provide some suggestions or insights to this error I observed.  I am using Appium to launch a simulator UICatelog and ran into this issue.

[screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOqWf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the missing jar file which contains the class `org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchSessionException`

Off the top of my head, I believe it is the selenium-api jar

Comment: Hi Doug, Thank you for your

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Doug.  I did look at selenium-api.jar but it doesn't seem to contain the class org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException.  Take a look http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadseleniumapi290jar.htm.  If you have any further recommendation, please feel free to let me know.